# Artifactory won't start after upgrade from 6.0.1 to 6.1.0

Tags: artifactory

I just upgraded my Artifactory OSS installation from the 6.0.1 release to 6.1.0.
After restarting the service I was puzzled why the instance was not coming up.
Looking at the artifactory.log I found this stacktrace:

```
2018-08-07 14:44:32,284 [art-init] [INFO ] (o.j.s.c.EncryptionWrapperFactory:33) - createArtifactoryKeyWrapper  EncryptionWrapperBase{ encodingType=ARTIFACTORY_MASTER, topEncrypter=BytesEncrypterBase{ Cipher='DESede',  keyId='31Qpu'}, formatUsed=OldFormat, decrypters=[BytesEncrypterBase{ Cipher='DESede',  keyId='31Qpu'}, BytesEncrypterBase{ Cipher='DESede',  keyId='31Qpu'}]}
2018-08-07 14:44:32,284 [art-init] [ERROR] (o.a.w.s.ArtifactoryContextConfigListener:92) - Application could not be initialized: Given final block not properly padded
java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException: null
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at org.artifactory.webapp.servlet.ArtifactoryContextConfigListener.configure(ArtifactoryContextConfigListener.java:207)
    at org.artifactory.webapp.servlet.ArtifactoryContextConfigListener.access$200(ArtifactoryContextConfigListener.java:63)
    at org.artifactory.webapp.servlet.ArtifactoryContextConfigListener$1.run(ArtifactoryContextConfigListener.java:88)
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanInitializationException: Failed to initialize bean 'org.artifactory.config.InternalCentralConfigService'.; nested exception is org.jfrog.security.crypto.exception.CryptoRuntimeException: javax.crypto.BadPaddingException: Given final block not properly padded
    at org.artifactory.spring.ArtifactoryApplicationContext.refresh(ArtifactoryApplicationContext.java:253)
    at org.artifactory.spring.ArtifactoryApplicationContext.<init>(ArtifactoryApplicationContext.java:136)
    ... 7 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.jfrog.security.crypto.exception.CryptoRuntimeException: javax.crypto.BadPaddingException: Given final block not properly padded
    at org.jfrog.security.crypto.EncryptionWrapperBase.decryptFallback(EncryptionWrapperBase.java:195)
    at org.jfrog.security.crypto.EncryptionWrapperBase.decrypt(EncryptionWrapperBase.java:129)
    at org.jfrog.security.crypto.EncryptionWrapperBase.decrypt(EncryptionWrapperBase.java:115)
    at org.jfrog.security.crypto.EncryptionWrapperBase.decrypt(EncryptionWrapperBase.java:101)
    at org.jfrog.security.crypto.EncryptionWrapperBase.decryptIfNeeded(EncryptionWrapperBase.java:92)
    at org.jfrog.security.crypto.EncryptionWrapperBase.encryptIfNeeded(EncryptionWrapperBase.java:253)
    at org.artifactory.common.crypto.CryptoHelper.encryptIfNeeded(CryptoHelper.java:73)
    at org.artifactory.layout.EncryptConfigurationInterceptor.getNewPassword(EncryptConfigurationInterceptor.java:181)
    at org.artifactory.layout.EncryptConfigurationInterceptor.encryptOrDecrypt(EncryptConfigurationInterceptor.java:112)
    at org.artifactory.layout.EncryptConfigurationInterceptor.encrypt(EncryptConfigurationInterceptor.java:203)
    at org.artifactory.layout.EncryptConfigurationInterceptor.onBeforeSave(EncryptConfigurationInterceptor.java:193)
    at org.artifactory.config.ConfigurationChangesInterceptorsImpl.onBeforeSave(ConfigurationChangesInterceptorsImpl.java:43)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:317)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:201)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy95.onBeforeSave(Unknown Source)
    at org.artifactory.config.CentralConfigServiceImpl.preSaveDescriptor(CentralConfigServiceImpl.java:319)
    at org.artifactory.config.CentralConfigServiceImpl.forceSaveDescriptorInternal(CentralConfigServiceImpl.java:377)
    at org.artifactory.config.CentralConfigServiceImpl.initCacheAndGetCurrent(CentralConfigServiceImpl.java:166)
    at org.artifactory.config.CentralConfigServiceImpl.init(CentralConfigServiceImpl.java:147)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:317)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:190)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:157)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor$1.proceedWithInvocation(TransactionInterceptor.java:99)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:281)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:96)
    at org.artifactory.storage.fs.lock.aop.LockingAdvice.invoke(LockingAdvice.java:76)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:207)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy96.init(Unknown Source)
    at org.artifactory.spring.ArtifactoryApplicationContext.refresh(ArtifactoryApplicationContext.java:251)
    ... 8 common frames omitted
Caused by: javax.crypto.BadPaddingException: Given final block not properly padded
    at com.sun.crypto.provider.CipherCore.doFinal(CipherCore.java:975)
    at com.sun.crypto.provider.CipherCore.doFinal(CipherCore.java:833)
    at com.sun.crypto.provider.PKCS12PBECipherCore.implDoFinal(PKCS12PBECipherCore.java:399)
    at com.sun.crypto.provider.PKCS12PBECipherCore$PBEWithSHA1AndDESede.engineDoFinal(PKCS12PBECipherCore.java:431)
    at javax.crypto.Cipher.doFinal(Cipher.java:2165)
    at org.jfrog.security.crypto.JFrogCryptoHelper.decryptSymmetric(JFrogCryptoHelper.java:302)
    at org.jfrog.security.crypto.encrypter.DESedeBytesEncrypter.decrypt(DESedeBytesEncrypter.java:43)
    at org.jfrog.security.crypto.EncryptionWrapperBase.decrypt(EncryptionWrapperBase.java:124)
    ... 44 common frames omitted
```

I found some topics where an upgrade from a pre 5.7.0 version could cause such problems but that did not fit here. I had the 6.0.1 up and running for some months now. Any idea what is causing this issue and how to fix it?

**EDIT**

It appears that this is related to [RTFACT-15580](https://www.jfrog.com/jira/browse/RTFACT-15580) in JFrog's JIRA-system. But there is not hint of how the badly encrypted data can be revoered. Any ideas? Or anyone who stumbled across the same problem?

Kind regards,

Sebastian

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Okay.

Here is the solution - **thanks to the JFrog support team**!
Somehow the artifactory installation key located under artifactory/etc/security/artifactory.key became corrupted which means it changed over time. Since artifactory stores all credentials in its configuration files encrypted with this key it was not able to decrypt the credentials. Thus it refused to start.

**Solution**:

For me removing the encrypted password of the email settings was sufficient.

1. Stop artifactory (if it is running for sure)
2. Copy the artifactory.config.latest.xml to artifactory.config.import.xml
3. Edit the copied file (the one with import in its name) and wipe out the password
4. Start artifactory
5. Re-enter the email password via the UI

I hope this helps anyone out having similar problems.